# Is this the correct method for deriving $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity

I was trying to derive Einstein's $$ E = mc^2$$

and I later found a derivation on [this website](http://www.emc2-explained.info/Emc2/Derive.htm).

They use a calculus-based method, so I tried another way. Here's my attempt.

The only equation of energy that is related to speed is: 
$$ E= \frac{1}{2} m v^2 $$

If we divide both sides with $ c^2$ then it yields $\frac {E}{c^2}=\frac{1}{2}m \frac{v^2}{c^2}$

Knowing that $v= \frac{v_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$, with some basic algebra skill, I got
$$E=\frac{1}{2}m \frac{v^2-V_0^2}{V_0^2}c^2$$

Since the value of $\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2-V_0^2}{V_0^2}$ is so small, we can neglect this expression. Therefore:

$$E=mc^2$$

So is it the right method? Please let me know.

Comment: That "small" value - when a value is "very small" relative to the other values, it can only be ignored if it is **added**. If it's **multiplied** then it has to be very close to unity for it to be reasonable to ignore it. A multiplied value that is "very small" pushes the entire expression closer to zero.

Answer (score 22):

No. The derivation of Einstein's $E=mc^2$ is not derivable from the simple Newtonian Mechanical formulae. Also, they are not, a priori, assumed to be true in the standard treatment of relativity.

Einstein starts with his own definition of simultaneity along with the postulates of the principle of relativity and the invariance of the speed of light. From these things, we arrive at $E=mc^2$ after assuming some particular conservation laws to be valid.

There is no way one can derive it from plain Newtonian Mechanics. Particularly, in your derivation, the most apparent mistakes are:

1. Equating energy at rest with the kinetic energy. ($E$ in Einstein's formula is energy at rest--not the kinetic energy.)
2. Incorrect approximation in the last step. If a term in multiplication is small, one should approximate it with a zero, not a one. And never with a two.

Comment: Thank you, so which formula i have to start with?

Comment: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html Here is a nice derivation.